# React Native: add Google Maps SDK

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add *Google Maps SDK* to my *React Native* project.

I am following the [official getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) and installing SDK through  *cocoapods*. But right after `pod install` I can't launch my project anymore:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      -[RCTJSCExecutor dealloc] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      executeRandomAccessModule(RCTJSCExecutor*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      readRAMBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<__sFILE, int (*)(__sFILE*)>, RandomAccessBundleData&) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      RandomAccessBundleData::~RandomAccessBundleData() in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      executeRandomAccessModule(RCTJSCExecutor*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      readRAMBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<__sFILE, int (*)(__sFILE*)>, RandomAccessBundleData&) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext initWithJSContext:onThread:] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext invalidate] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      RCTNSErrorFromJSError(RCTJSCWrapper*, OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue const*) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor initWithUseCustomJSCLibrary:] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FooTests.xctest/FooTests normal x86_64
(1 failure)
/Users/admin/Desktop/Foo/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: xcodebuild process exited with code 65
    at ChildProcess.xcodeBuildProcess.on.code (/Users/admin/Desktop/Foo/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:93:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
```

Has someone managed to add Google Map SDK to a React Native project?

P.S. I saw [this project](https://github.com/peterprokop/ReactNativeGoogleMaps) but it is too old, I can't even run it.

Comment: I did it last year. What a headache. I had to manually add a bunch of files, go through the stack trace, and change some of the macros they use(which prevents you from updating) blah blah blah. It wasn't worth it in the end. If you can just use apple maps or component already created where you can extend your own functionality. Sorry it's not much help just some advice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I'll drop React Native for this project and just use plain Swfit/Obj-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in using Google Maps with `React Native` - use [`Airbnb react-native-maps`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps). On iOS you can set a `provider` to `google maps` and [add a custom styling](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps#customizing-the-map-style)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use [the `react-native-google-maps` library](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps) to solve this without cocoapods and it is quite easy to integrate and use

Comment: Thanks, I saw this lib, but it uses Apple Maps on iOS... Apple Maps can't be custom styled like Google Maps. That's why I need Google Maps..